# Meaning of blossom in the given sentence/meaning of the sentece

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't think you should tell him about the conversations that **blossomed** between us the other day.

What does the sentence mean? 
Does it, in its most basic sense, mean "don't tell...the conversations that we had the other day"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. However, there is a slight difference. *Blossomed* is synonymous *developed* in this example:

> [blossom](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blossom?s=t)
>   verb (used without object)
>   4. to flourish; develop (often followed by into or out):
>   *a writer of commercial jingles who blossomed out into an important composer.*
>   (Dictionary.com)

The writer is not simply talking about the conversations they *had*, but about the conversations that *developed*. The nuance is that *blossom* is something flowers do. In your example, the verb *blossom* is used figuratively and that usage could be considered poetic, or artistic.

Answer (score 0):

The on-line Oxford Dictionary defines 'blossom' in meaning 1.1. as:

> Mature or develop in a promising or healthy way  [Oxford - Blossom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blossom)

So the speaker does not just mean that these two people had a conversation, but that the conversation went beyond trivial day-to-day matters and went into deeper, possibly more personal, areas. The use of the word 'blossom' indicates that the speaker, and possibly the person they were speaking to, considered that conversation to be healthy and productive, much as a healthy plant blossoms by producing new growth and flowers.